# Xamarin iOS App crashing after Xcode [8.0] and Xamarin Studio update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I updated Xcode to `Xcode 8.0` and `Xamarin Studio to 6.1.1` (build 15), after which the iOS apps won't run on either debug or release modes in either the simulator or a real device. (checked on two iPhones; iOS 9.3.1, and iOS 10). 
The application simply crashes after the launch screen, so there is no way of finding out what's causing it.

I have looked at many other similar issues that users have submitted here and also in `Xamarin` forums, and played around with Debug configurations, as well as iOS build configurations in `Xamarin Studio`, but still no luck.

I have tried running a new empty project, and it seems to work on both simulator and the real device.

I also checked for Xcode device crash logs, and there seem to be only a handful even though the issue still exists. I have attached the most recent log below.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @executable_path/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/698A401E-3748-4DDA-AE74-9730F831645E/Fiud.iOS.app/Fiud.iOS
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/containers/Bundle/Application/698A401E-3748-4DDA-AE74-9730F831645E/Fiud.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x0037D000, size=0x00194000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /var/containers/Bundle/Application/698A401E-3748-4DDA-AE74-9730F831645E/Fiud.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/698A401E-3748-4DDA-AE74-9730F831645E/Fiud.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x00605000, size=0x00194000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/698A401E-3748-4DDA-AE74-9730F831645E/Fiud.iOS.app/libmonosgen-2.0.dylib
  Dyld Version: 390.7

Binary Images:
0x65000 - 0x120fff Fiud.iOS armv7  <ebf059a9d4513e27bdfc538cf4ac08ac> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/698A401E-3748-4DDA-AE74-9730F831645E/Fiud.iOS.app/Fiud.iOS
0x1fe15000 - 0x1fe3cfff dyld armv7s  <d96d5b718d2b3c3bad7f17d4e8a3f049> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Would be a big help if someone could help, been stuck with this issue for two days now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning? It's cmd+alt+shift+K for Xcode. Dunno why it works but works a lot of the times for me.

Comment: @WoominJoshPark I tried cleaning the app many times via Xamarin Studio. With no luck.

Comment: Also removed the Derived Data folder too?

Comment: I had a similar error some time ago. Please check your linker settings. The linker option "SDK only" does not always works perfect. Change the setting to "None" - the App will be bigger, but all assemblies will be included.

Comment: Is it happening in Debug or Release configuration? Try also disabling incremental deployment.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @CaseyHancock i don't think so. I had to create a new project and replace the existing classes to get it to work. I also remember reverting back to old versions of Xcode and Xamarin Studio.